# Verbo sbagliato, il mezzo non è l'agente?

Tags: grammatical-analysis

Mi scuso per il titolo che può essere fuorviante, nel caso dovesse essere sbagliato correggetemi e lo cambierò volentieri.

Stavo rileggendo la tesi della mia ragazza e ho trovato un passaggio in cui commenta delle tesi fatte in precedenza. Ogni tesi riguarda un particolare vigneto ed ognuna spiega le analisi ed i cambiamenti del vigneto durante un certo periodo.

Le frasi incriminate sono per esempio: *la tesi subisce un calo dell'acidità* oppure *le tesi assumono un comportamento simile riguardo l'accumulo di zuccheri*. Io le ho corrette dicendo che non è la tesi a subire il calo dell'acidità, bensì il vigneto descritto all'interno della tesi. Lei però non trova giusta la mia correzione.

Sono abbastanza sicuro di quello che ho corretto (una frase del genere potrebbe andar bene nel parlato), ma non ho le competenze per spiegarle perchè dal punto di vista logico la frase sia sbagliata. Quello che mi viene in mente è che il mezzo usato per raccontare non è l'agente stesso che fa l'azione. Avete qualche risorsa da consigliarmi per spiegare la giusta costruzione?

Vi ringrazio molto, qualsiasi risposta sarà per me molto interessante da leggere.

P.S. so che il tag migliore sarebbe "analisi logica" ma non ho abbastanza reputazione per crearne uno nuovo e l'unico che esiste e mi sembra calzante è analisi grammaticale.

Comment: Nel complesso sono perfettamente d'accordo con le tue critiche. Non sono però sicuro di capire bene il secondo esempio: “assumere” nel senso di “dare per scontato, prendere come ipotesi” oppure con “le tesi assumono un comportamento X” intende che “le tesi si comportano nel modo X”?

Comment: Lei vorrebbe dire " durante il periodo di maturazione, tutte le vigne assumono un comportamento pressochè simile riguardo l'accumulo di zuccheri". Quello che lei ha scritto è " durante il periodo di maturazione, tutte le tesi assumono un comportamento pressochè simile riguardo l'accumulo di zuccheri", intendendo per "tesi" le "vigne" in quanto ogni tesi descrive una vigna.

Comment: Ah, allora ti do sicuramente ragione, sia perché è un po' strano leggere che le tesi accumulano zuccheri, sia perché – per quel che scrivevo prima – non è immediatamente chiaro il senso. Mi chiedo perché la tua ragazza si esprima così: può essere che ci siano altri testi impostati in modo simile? (Il che comunque non toglierebbe che sia un modo discutibile di esprimersi.)

Comment: Non saprei infatti è proprio per quello che ho scritto su stack. Secondo me la regola è che semplicemente il soggetto non si addice al verbo, un po' come se in un articolo di giornale si parlasse di un killer, e io scrivessi " il giornale ha ammazzato.. ". Conosci come si chiama questo errore? A me sembrerebbe semplicemente logica.

Comment: La penso come te. Mi chiedevo solo se tante volte fosse influenzata da testi, non so, del suo docente o di altri colleghi. A volte in un ambiente specifico si diffondono peculiarità linguistiche che al di fuori suonano strane e basta, come quei fisici italiani che parlano di “targhette” intendendo “bersagli” (dall'inglese *target*). Comunque non c'è dubbio che i giornali non ammazzano e le tesi non sono zuccherine.

Comment: Una tesi può assumere, nel senso che l'autore fa un'assunzione, un'ipotesi. Quindi la seconda frase sarebbe corretta, se non fosse che sono le vigne ad “assumere un comportamento”. Di certo le tesi non subiscono cali di acidità (se non si parla della carta su cui sono stampate), nemmeno nel parlato.

Comment: Sembra un tentativo non riuscito di metonimia (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/metonimia_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), in cui "la vigna di cui si parla nella tesi" diventa, semplicemente, "la tesi". Ma è davvero strano: ha teso troppo il filo dello logica.

Comment: Grazie Benedetta cercavo proprio una spiegazione del genere. Comunque  ho parlato alla mia ragazza il giorno seguente e mi ha dato ragione, probabilmente era molto stanca dato che ha lavorato alla tesi fino a tardi. E' stato comunque interessante parlare con voi, ho imparato qualcosa grazie mille!

Comment: Può capitare, la tua ragazza non deve crucciarsi :-)

Comment: @egreg In questo caso non direi "la tesi assume", ma "nella tesi l'autore assume".

Comment: @FedericoPoloni La metonimia “la tesi‘ per ”l'autore della tesi” potrebbe anche andare, ma il senso verrebbe diverso.